# DSPIC33 SPI Master chip select line not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, microchip

Ive been trying really hard to get the SPI bus working on a DSPIC33EP128GM604. Ive configured SPI3 as a standard 8 bit master module and have designated a chip select pin so I can toggle slave devices.

I cannot get the chip select line to work properly, it seems as if the DSPIC does not wait for transmission to complete before toggling the chip select line from LOW to HIGH. Ive checked the Erratas and nothing seems relevant to this problem. Furthermore ive tried to swap the CS line to some other pin. Ive also tried SPI module 1, but problem persists.

Here is my code:

SPI 3 configuration:

```
void Init_SPI3 ( void )
{
IFS5bits.SPI3IF = 0; // Clear the Interrupt flag
IEC5bits.SPI3IE = 0; // Disable the interrupt
// SPI1CON1 Register Settings
SPI3CON1bits.DISSCK = 0; // Internal serial clock is enabled
SPI3CON1bits.DISSDO = 0; // SDOx pin is controlled by the module
SPI3CON1bits.MODE16 = 0; // Communication is word-wide (16 bits)
SPI3CON1bits.SSEN = 0; //No CS
SPI3CON1bits.MSTEN = 1; // Master mode disabled
SPI3CON1bits.PPRE = 2; //Pre-scaler
SPI3CON1bits.SPRE = 8;//Pre-scaler 2
SPI3CON1bits.SMP =1; // Input data is sampled at the middle of data output time
SPI3CON1bits.CKE =0; // Serial output data changes on transition from
SPI3CON1bits.CKP = 0; // Idle state for clock is a low level;
SPI3STATbits.SPIEN = 1; // Enable SPI module
// Interrupt Controller Settings
IFS5bits.SPI3IF = 0; // Clear the Interrupt flag
IEC5bits.SPI3IE = 1; // Enable the interrupt
}
```

SPI 3 Pin configuration:

```
TRISBbits.TRISB10 = 0; //Set SPI3CLK as output
TRISBbits.TRISB11 = 0; //Set SPI3DATAOUT as output

RPOR4bits.RP42R=32;  //SPI3_CLK out
RPOR4bits.RP43R=31;  //SPI3_DATA out
```

Chip select line pin configuration:

```
TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 0; //SPI3 CS is on Pin B4, set it to Output
```

Simple main routine:

```
    while(1==1){

    PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;//Set CS line to low  
   WriteSPI3(0xaa); //This is from the peripheral library to be safe....
  PORTBbits.RB4 = 1; //Set CS line to high
                    }
```

But here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Specifically, what is the problem that I should be seeing in the scope pic?

Comment: Where are you setting the SPI mode w/ CPOL and CPHA

Comment: the bits .CKE and .CKP?

Comment: Sorry -- been a long time since using a dsPIC, and I'm used to STM32F CMSIS calls.  Are you sure those values are right for the device you're trying to talk with?

Comment: I havnt even tried that yet. The problem is the CS line is not being toggled correctly. If you look at the purple trace (CS) it changes state prematurely. Im quite fed up with DSPIC tbh, im giving it one more day before I switch to the STM32s....

Comment: Why can't you leave the CS bit low, and toggle it on the other side, just before you set it high?  Is it in the way of something?  Set the appropriate CS right before doing communication, and leave it there till the next loop through.

Comment: afaik this is a part with enhanced mode. The meaning of the flags changes in enhanced mode. Make sure that you turn enhanced mode OFF   (see spi<x>con2.SPIBEN bit)

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet and example codes, the Receive Buffer Flag is sufficient to tell us when the TX event is complete and thus the CS can toggle. It is a bit strange why there isnt a flag for this chip that tells us when the SPI shift register has transmitted all its data. All the example code only check the Receive buffer flag.

After a lot of head scratching, trial and error and finally the microchip forums, i can confirm **that this code works**:

```
   uint8_t Write_SPI1(uint8_t command) { //Does work    
    SPI1BUF = command; // send data over SPI
    while(!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF) ; //wait until SPIRBF goes high  
    return SPI1BUF; //KEY STATEMENT THAT MADE A DIFFERENCE, Return the actual data received
    }
```

Along with this code, if your peripheral depends on Peripheral Pin Select (SPI2,SPI3 etc), it is important to define not only a SPI Clock Out but also a SPI Clock In **even if you are in master mode**

However, what is rather baffling to me is that this code (that i think should do the same thing) does not work:

```
  void Write_SPI1(uint8_t command) { //Does not work, premature toggle of CS, tried this code initially....
    uint8_t garbage;
    SPI1BUF = command; // send data over SPI
    while(!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF) ; //wait until SPIRBF goes high 
    garbage = SPI1BUF; // read dummy data, does not seem to clear the flag as expected
    }
```

Comment: Odd.  Just a thought -- have you tried turning optimization off before you compile??  Looks like your compiler is taking shortcuts you don't want it to take, and turning optimization off might make things better.

Comment: In fact, the compiler might see "garbage" as never being used, and optimize out the whole line.  It can't optimize away a return value.

Comment: ... or, try adding volatile to the garbage declaration.

Comment: adding volatile does not work. But returning garbage instead of SPI1BUF also works. Hmmm, sounds like a compiler perk.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the SPI transmission is complete before un-asserting the chip select with something like

```
 while(SPI3_Tx_Buf_Full);  //wait till completion of transmission
```

See the example using SPI1 at http://pat.cybersites.ca/docs/PIC24F/SPI_Example1.html

Comment: I assumed the peripheral library would take care of that. Nonetheless i found the equivalent flag for my chip:

`while(SPI3STATbits.SPITBF){};`

Makes no difference, is the flag being set incorrectly by the module somehow?

Comment: `SPITBF` only indicates whether or not there are bits in the buffer, not whether it is still transmitting. After the `while` statement you added, try `while(!SPI3STATbits.SPIRBF)` to hold until transmission is finished and something has been put in the receive buffer (even if you don't do anything with it).

Comment: `SPI3_Tx_Buf_Full` should be a macro testing the correct bit.  You are asserting CS yourself with `PORTBbits.RB4 = 0`, so likewise you have to unassert it yourself.  You just need to wait for the peripheral to finish shifting the bits out.  If the library did it by itself AFTER starting atransfer, that would just waste CPU cycles you might want to use some other way.  There may be a built-in test before writing the next value inside `WriteSPI3`.   But that's before starting the peripheral, not after

Comment: I tried to add: `while(!SPI3STATbits.SPIRBF)`: No change, other than the fact that the CS is asserted for slightly longer and i only get one transmission after which the Pic does nothing, so it clearly loops at this while statement.

Comment: @AdilMalik you're confusing the TX Buffer with the TX Shift Register. The Shift Register is where the bits are actually sent from, while the Buffer is where your code loads them. The module internally transfers your data byte from the Buffer to the Shift Register as it's getting ready to send it (giving you a SPITBF flag indication), but at this point, the bits are still in the Shift Register and haven't been sent out yet. if you use SPIRBF as a flag to tell you when the transaction is complete you need to make sure you empty the RX Buffer first so the the SPIRBF flag starts off cleared.

Comment: Perhaps SPIxSTAT.SPIBUSY might work if SPITBE isn't doing it.

Comment: Or setting SPIxSTAT.SISEL to mode 5 (0b101) and use the SPI interrupt as a flag to indicate when the last bit has been sent.

Comment: Tried all the suggestions, nothing seems to work:

1) SPIxSTAT.SPIBUSY is not a valid bit for my device
2) Created a interrupt function: `void __attribute__((interrupt,auto_psv)) _SPI3Interrupt(void)             
 {                                                                        
  PORTBbits.RB4 = 1; 
             
}`

and set .SISEL to 5. Still no change

Im starting to think is this a possible bug?

Comment: I'm assuming you did remember to comment out the **RB4=1** in your main loop ...? Although I wouldn't actually use an interrupt function - just wait in your main loop for the interrupt flag to be set with **while (!whatever_the_irq_flag_bit_is);**

Comment: And if you're trying the SPIxRBF method, make sure that the RBF flag is cleared before you begin transmitting.

Comment: @AdilMalik - "is this a possible bug?" Assuming your -CS signal is the purple line on your 'scope photo, then **no**, I would not be looking for a DSPIC33 bug. That is because a -CS signal like that purple line would never work for a normal SPI slave, and a bug as serious as that would be well-known. I don't use that MCU, but if I was in your position, in addition to the helpful advice you are receiving, I would start by looking for working sample SPI code. Here is an EE.SE thread which contains a [claimed-to-be-working SPI Master example](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/91656/).

Comment: I have looked at many Microchip provided SPI examples. To begin with the code they provide have conflicting values for when the flag is in TX state etc. However, the core method is just as a lot of the people above have suggested. Here is one from the "Example Code" section of the DSPIC.

Comment: `void Write_SPI1 ( int16_t command )
{
    int16_t temp;

    PORTBbits.RB7 = 0;                          // lower the slave select line
    temp = SPI1BUF;                             // dummy read of the SPI1BUF register to clear the SPIRBF flag
    SPI1BUF = command;                          // write the data out to the SPI peripheral
    while( !SPI1STATbits.SPITBF )               // wait for the data to be sent out
        ;
    PORTBbits.RB7 = 1;                          // raise the slave select line
}`

Comment: `void Write_SPI2 ( int16_t command )
{
    int16_t temp;

    PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;                          // lower the slave select line
    temp = SPI1BUF;                             // dummy read of the SPI1BUF register to clear the SPIRBF flag
    SPI1BUF = command;                          // write the data out to the SPI peripheral
    while( !SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF )               // wait for the data to be sent out
        ;
    PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;                          // raise the slave select line
}`

Comment: So for the functionally same routine they are checking 2 difernet flags, nonetheless the idea is the same. It does not work in both cases. **But if i waste a few cycles with a for loop, the CS pin toggles correctly as expected**